# update sendgrid personalizations json file through powershell

Tags: json, powershell, sendgrid

Want to update below sendgrid personalizations json file through powershell to add one more email id.

From:-

```
{
    "personalizations": [{
        "to": [{"email": "abc1@xyz.com"}, {"email": "abc2@xyz.com"}]
    }]
}
```

To:-

```
{
    "personalizations": [{
        "to": [{"email": "abc1@xyz.com"}, {"email": "abc2@xyz.com"}, {"email": "abc3@xyz.com"}]
    }]
}
```

Have tried saving it to file and using Add-Member but that did not work.

```
$EmailTemplateFilePath = "C:\EmailTemplate.json"
$body = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($EmailTemplateFilePath)
$body = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $body
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Parse the input JSON into a custom object ([pscustomobject]).
$obj = (@'
{
  "personalizations": [{
      "to": [{"email": "abc1@xyz.com"}, {"email": "abc2@xyz.com"}]
  }]
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json)

# Append a new custom object with a new email address.
$obj.personalizations[0].to += [pscustomobject] @{ email = 'abc3@xyz.com' }

# Convert back to JSON.
$obj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

Note the unfortunate need for `-Depth 3` to ensure that the parsed-from-JSON object is properly converted back to JSON - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8393).

The above yields:

```json
{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        "@{email=abc1@xyz.com}",
        "@{email=abc2@xyz.com}",
        "@{email=abc3@xyz.com}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @KushalSolanki; my pleasure.